# Groupdocs conversion using streams

Tags: java, mongodb, nullpointerexception, groupdocs

I need to be able to convert .pdf documents into preview/thumbnail images for later retrieval.  It's working now in my solution, which currently involves dumping new files into a watched folder, writing the converted files to disk, and then pushing them into a MongoDB collection.  But I want to do it without writing any files to disk.  (The image files themselves will be going into a MongoDB collection, and the content from which the image files will be generated comes from a different MongoDB collection.)  I'm using groupdocs conversion to do this.

I have one class which retrieves the content and passes it as an InputStream into another class, whose method of interest goes like this:

```
public void generateRenderedImages(InputStream inputStream, String fileName, ConversionHandler conversionHandler) {

    File previewImage = null;
    File thumbnailImage = null;
    File parent = null;

    try {
        ImageSaveOptions imageSaveOptions = new ImageSaveOptions();
        imageSaveOptions.setSaveFileType(ImageSaveOptions.JPEG);
        imageSaveOptions.setPage(1);
        imageSaveOptions.setHeight(THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT);
        imageSaveOptions.setWidth(THUMBNAIL_WIDTH);
        imageSaveOptions.setSavePath(null);

        // generate preview image
        imageSaveOptions.setSaveName("blah.jpg");

        OutputStream outputStream = conversionHandler.convertToImage(inputStream, fileName, imageSaveOptions);

        saveToDatabase(outputStream, CONTENT_TYPE_PREVIEW, fileName);

        imageSaveOptions.setHeight(THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT);
        imageSaveOptions.setWidth(THUMBNAIL_WIDTH);

        outputStream.close();

        outputStream = conversionHandler.convertToImage(inputStream, fileName, imageSaveOptions);
        saveToDatabase(outputStream, CONTENT_TYPE_THUMBNAIL, fileName);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("Image rendering failed); error = " + e.getMessage());
        resLogger.writeLog("Image rendering failed); error = " + e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        // maybe need something here, not sure yet
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm throwing a NullPointerException at the conversionHandler.convertToImage(...) line -- relevant parts of the stack trace will follow -- even though neither the conversionHandler nor any of its parameters are null.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.groupdocs.conversion.converter.a.(ConversionHelper.java:31)
>       at com.groupdocs.conversion.handler.ConversionHandler.convertToImage(ConversionHandler.java:127)

I have done some research into this, but the relative lack of documentation that I can find has created some limits.  For example, this page:

https://github.com/groupdocs/groupdocs-conversion-java-maven-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/groupdocs/conversion/maven/converters/ToImageSampleConversion.java

...positively shows in this snippet that this is possible, and at least in theory how:

> /**
>        * Convert 1 document page to images
>        * On this type of conversion convertToImage returns OutputStream with converted file
>        * Note: converted file is not saved in local directory
>        * To use this type of conversion 'page' and 'saveToStream' parameters must be set in ImageSaveOptions
>        * convertToImage method also can receive InputStream as parameter
>        * See JavaDoc for more info.
>        * @param conversionHandler ConversionHandler instance
>        * @param page page number
>        */
>       public void convertToStream(ConversionHandler conversionHandler, int page){
>           ImageSaveOptions imageSaveOptions = new ImageSaveOptions();
>           imageSaveOptions.setSaveFileType(ImageSaveOptions.PNG);
>           imageSaveOptions.setPage(page);

```
    OutputStream outputStream = conversionHandler.convertToImage(PDF_FILE, imageSaveOptions);
    //do something with the stream
```

Unfortunately there is no setSaveToStream() method, but I found from this page:

http://groupdocs.com/Community/files/9/java-libraries/groupdocs_conversion_for_java/entry5343.aspx

that in the previous version this was removed:

> Public Api changes
>   ...
>   com.groupdocs.conversion.option.SaveOptions
>   The method setSaveToStream  was removed to simplify options parameters.
>   Now for saving result document to stream output just do not set SaveOptions.setSavePath or set it to null.

So I don't have to explicitly set the saveToStream property, I just have to make sure savePath is null.  Which I have done, and yet the problem persists.  I've tried every other combination of setting/not setting properties, all with the same result.

I'm using version 1.2.0 of groupdocs conversion.  Anyone see this before, and know why I might be getting a NPE when nothing is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was away from this for a while, but got back to it today.

Here is my solution:

```
public class RenderImages {
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(RenderImages.class);

public static void generateRenderedImages(Datastore datastore,
    InputStream inputStream,
    String fileName,
    ConversionHandler conversionHandler,
    SystemProperties systemProperties,
    Logger logger) {

    int thumbnailHeight = systemProperties.getAsInteger("RENDER_THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT");
    int thumbnailWidth = systemProperties.getAsInteger("RENDER_THUMBNAIL_WIDTH");
    String contentTypePreview = systemProperties.get("RENDER_CONTENT_TYPE_PREVIEW");
    String contentTypeThumbnail = systemProperties.get("RENDER_CONTENT_TYPE_THUMBNAIL");

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        byte[] imageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
        inputStream.close();

        ImageSaveOptions imageSaveOptions = new ImageSaveOptions();
        imageSaveOptions.setSaveFileType(ImageSaveOptions.JPEG);
        imageSaveOptions.setPage(1);

        ByteArrayOutputStream previewStream = conversionHandler.convertToImage(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes),
            fileName + ".pdf",
            imageSaveOptions);

        saveToDatabase(datastore, previewStream, contentTypePreview, fileName);
        previewStream.close();

        imageSaveOptions.setHeight(thumbnailHeight);
        imageSaveOptions.setWidth(thumbnailWidth);

        ByteArrayOutputStream thumbnailStream = conversionHandler.convertToImage(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes),
            fileName + ".pdf",
            imageSaveOptions);

        saveToDatabase(datastore, thumbnailStream, contentTypeThumbnail, fileName);
        thumbnailStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.error("Image rendering failed); error = " + e.getMessage());
        logger.writeLog("Image rendering failed); error = " + e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        // maybe need something here, not sure yet
    }
}

private static void saveToDatabase(Datastore datastore,
    ByteArrayOutputStream image, String contentType, String fileName) throws IOException {

    RenderedImage renderedImage = datastore.find(RenderedImage.class)
        .filter("attachmentId", fileName)
        .filter("contentType", contentType)
        .get();

    if (renderedImage == null) {
        renderedImage = new RenderedImage();
        renderedImage.setAttachmentId(fileName);
        renderedImage.setContentType(contentType);
        renderedImage.setContent(image.toByteArray());
        datastore.save(renderedImage);
    }
}
```

}